# Facebook Android SDK 4.14.0 get birthday

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm currently creating a test application to test using the latest facebook SDK to update our existing application problem is that I need to get the user birthday.  I'm confused on this since the the SDK3 and above provides more information than the updated SDK4 and I'm lost on how to get the birthday as all the answers I've seen so far doesn't provide the birthday on my end. Here's my code so far:

**LoginButton CallBacks:**

```
 fbLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    fbLogin.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday"));

    fbLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {


                    try {

                        if (object.has("id"))
                            id = object.getString("id");
                        if (object.has("name"))
                            userName = object.getString("name");
                        if (object.has("email"))
                            userEmail = object.getString("email");
                        if (object.has("gender"))
                            gender = object.getString("gender");
                        if (object.has("birthday"))
                            birthday = object.getString("birthday");

                        String profile_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id+ "/picture?type=large";


                        LogCat.show(id + "\n" + userName + "\n" + userEmail + "\n" + birthday + "\n" + profile_URL + "\n" + gender);


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        LogCat.show("Error:" + e.getMessage());
                    }

                }
            });


            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email,gender, birthday");

            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code

            Toast.makeText(SplashLogin.this, "CANCEL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code

            Toast.makeText(SplashLogin.this, "" + exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

The JSON response returns only the ID and name, email and gender of my account but doesn't include the birthday. Did I missed out something?

Comment: Did you input your birthday and make it public?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the latest sdk of facebook, to get birthday you need to first submit your application for review. On test applications you can just get the public profile which includes the following things

- id
- cover
- name
- first_name
- last_name
- age_range
- link
- gender
- locale
- picture
- timezone
- updated_time
- verified

For more information you can read the following documentation from this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile)

Answer (score 1):

> If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to review how
>   your app uses it. [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference-user_birthday)

Facebook don't give user birthday by default.You have to use extended permissions.

Comment: Yes our business idea to provide some bonus or extra point to customer on his/her birthday

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by enable permission of Birthday in my app from the Facebook Developer Console.

```
 fbSignUp.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {


                    try {
                        Data.fbAccessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();

                        LogCat.show(loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());

                        if (object.has("id")) {
                            id = object.getString("id");
                            Data.fbId = object.getString("id");
                        }
                        if (object.has("name")) {
                            userName = object.getString("name");
                            ;
                            Data.fbUserName = object.getString("name");
                        }
                        if (object.has("email")) {
                            userEmail = object.getString("email");
                            Data.fbUserEmail = object.getString("email");
                        }


                        if (object.has("birthday")) {
                            userBirthDay = object.getString("birthday");
                        }
                        else {
                            if (userEmail == null || "".equalsIgnoreCase(userEmail)) {
                                if (userName != null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(userName)) {
                                    userEmail = userName + "@facebook.com";
                                    Data.fbUserEmail = Data.fbUserName + "@facebook.com";
                                } else {
                                    userEmail = id + "@facebook.com";
                                    Data.fbUserEmail = Data.fbId + "@facebook.com";
                                }
                            }
                        }



                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        LogCat.show("Error:" + e.getMessage());
                    }

                }
            });


            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email,birthday,gender");

            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code

            Toast.makeText(RegisterScreen.this, "CANCEL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code

            Toast.makeText(RegisterScreen.this, "" + exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```